# Update database with nested for loops?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I update the answer's descriptions to my database?

I have a working code for updating the question description.

Whenever I click update only the question description is updating not the answers.

I've added some codes...

Here is my new code but it doesnt seem to work either:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($selected); $i++)
{
    $sql = sprintf("UPDATE exam_questions SET question_description = '%s' WHERE question_id = '%s'", 
           mysql_real_escape_string($question[$i]), 
           mysql_real_escape_string($selected[$i]));
    mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM exam_answers WHERE answer_question_set_id = '".$selected[$i]."'")or die(mysql_error());
    $count=mysql_num_rows($sql);

    for($e = 0; $e<$count; $e++){
    $sql = sprintf("UPDATE exam_answers SET answer_description = '%s' WHERE answer_question_set_id = '%s'",
           mysql_real_escape_string($answer[$e]), 
           mysql_real_escape_string($answerid[$e]));
    mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: is the question id field an integer or a string?

Comment: its an integer. its on the value attrib of the checkbox i forgot to mention

Comment: You are overriding the $x variable in the second for-loop, you should use another variable-name instead :)

Comment: http://php.net/array_map - see the usage example with `NULL` as first parameter in *Example #4 Creating an array of arrays*. - however with select boxes it's likely not working or you've added numeric indexes into the input names.

Comment: It starts with well indenting the code, see my edit. However I still suggest to close this question because most likely there is more than one error and you don't have any (very little, only if a database query really fails) error checking in the code so you leave the work here to those who are kind enough and try to answer your question. Instead think about how you could better troubleshoot your code. Are all pre-conditions checked?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use $x in

```
for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($answer); $x++){
    **$x** = sprintf("UPDATE exam_answers SET answer_description = '%s' WHERE answer_question_set_id = '%s'",
           mysql_real_escape_string($answer[$x]), 
           mysql_real_escape_string($answerid[$x]));
    mysql_query($x)or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Instead use another variable of your choice. this will complicate to your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($answer); $x++){
    $x = sprintf("UPDATE exam_answers SET answer_description = '%s' WHERE answer_question_set_id = '%s'",
           mysql_real_escape_string($answer[$x]), 
           mysql_real_escape_string($answerid[$x]));
    mysql_query($x)or die(mysql_error());
}
```

You should do this:

```
for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($answer); $x++){
    $sql = sprintf("UPDATE exam_answers SET answer_description = '%s' WHERE answer_question_set_id = '%s'",
           mysql_real_escape_string($answer[$x]), 
           mysql_real_escape_string($answerid[$x]));
    mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Notice the replacement of "$x" with "$sql" like in the first for-loop.